# FTP difference between STOR and PUT command

Tags: windows, ftp, ftp-client

We use FTP for dropping the product feeds to our FTP server.

I wanted to understand the difference between the `STOR` and `PUT` command in FTP. Can you please help me understand this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `STOR` is an *FTP protocol* command for uploading a file.

The `PUT` (or rather `put`) is a common command in command-line *FTP clients* (such as the built-in Windows `ftp.exe`, [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put), or a common *nix `ftp`) for uploading a file.

When you use the `put` command in an FTP *client*, it issues a sequence of FTP *protocol* commands to the server, out of which, the most significant one is the `STOR`.

An example from Windows `ftp.exe` (with `-d` debug switch):

```
ftp> put test.txt
---> PORT 10,1,2,3,194,139
200 Port command successful
---> STOR test.txt
150 Opening data channel for file upload to server of "/test.txt"
226 Successfully transferred "/test.txt"
ftp: 3 bytes sent in 0.01Seconds 0.33Kbytes/sec.
ftp>
```